# 19.10 - NVMe - blk_update_request errors

Tags: kernel, dell, ssd, 19.10, nvme

So I have a Dell XPS 9560 with a SK Hynix PC400 NVMe 512GB drive. I had this drive in my Latitude 7480 previously with 19.04 and all was fine. When I moved the drive to the 9560 I clean installed 19.10. Since installing 19.10 I have had tons of "blk_update_request: operation not supported error, dev nvme0n1" errors. Within an hour my log file was up to about 50k lines and mostly these. When I was on 19.04 I I didn't have any of these errors. My firmware is set to SATA mode AHCI. My only other option is RAID and the installer doesn't see the drive at all with that mode. Searching on here someone mentioned putting their MSI board to Win7 install mode. Being a Dell I don't have that option. Is there anything I can do to fix this? Kernel was (5.3). No updates available.

Edit (info added):

```
=== START OF SMART DATA SECTION ===
SMART/Health Information (NVMe Log 0x02)
Critical Warning:                   0x00
Temperature:                        43 Celsius
Available Spare:                    100%
Available Spare Threshold:          50%
Percentage Used:                    2%
Data Units Read:                    11,815,319 [6.04 TB]
Data Units Written:                 28,650,780 [14.6 TB]
Host Read Commands:                 92,632,129
Host Write Commands:                130,327,513
Controller Busy Time:               17,482
Power Cycles:                       1,854
Power On Hours:                     1,489
Unsafe Shutdowns:                   157
Media and Data Integrity Errors:    0
Error Information Log Entries:      0
Warning  Comp. Temperature Time:    0
Critical Comp. Temperature Time:    0
Temperature Sensor 1:               43 Celsius
Temperature Sensor 2:               72 Celsius
```

I have thousands of these lines:

```
Feb  5 18:18:25 XPS-9560 kernel: [  114.675969] blk_update_request: operation not supported error, dev nvme0n1, sector 214996228 op 0x9:(WRITE_ZEROES) flags 0x0 phys_seg 0 prio class 0
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/104193/discussion-on-question-by-roxana-19-10-nvme-blk-update-request-errors).

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved. WD Black SN750 install to replaced SL Hynix PC 400. No more errors. Install on PC400 took 35ish minutes. Install on SN750 took 2. PC400 appears to be OEM limited and replaced by the PC401 shortly after release.